# Having trouble setting up dev server for Django and website

Tags: python, django, git, virtualenv, django-south

I am new to Python and Django. I am attempting to clone a repo from our remote/live server to a dev server at home so i can work on the website without worry as I am pretty much clueless still when it comes to Django. Unfortunately I cannot seem to get the site running. From what I understand the process should go something like this:

1] Create home folder for repo

2] virtualenv the folder

3] source the folder/bin/activate

4] clone repo into folder

5] pip requirements.txt of repo to install dependencies

6] syncdb

7] migrate data with south

8] profit

However when i get to step 6 "syncdb" I get a "Database Error: no such table: django_site". Doh, i forgot to point the settings file at an sqlite3 db. So i edited settings.py and commented out the actual db information and set the user/pass to "", set the ENGINE to "django.db.backend.sqlite3" and specified a "temp.db" and tried again but I am still getting the same error. Any help would be great, feel free to knock any wholes in my process i listed up there, i really want to do this the best way.

```
My database settings are :
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backend.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'db.sqlite3',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting "Database Error: no such table: django_site" chances are you didn't run 'syncdb' after you properly set the database settings.

Comment: I have included my database settings in the original post if you don't mind verifying them for me.

Comment: Turns out the previous dev who was a Jedi master setup a conditional in the settings.py to detect the dev server, i was mangling the connection settings for no reason.